# Language redirection with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, seo, translation

I'm totally  clueless when it comes to mod_rewrite, so I'll be glad to get any help. I just want Apache to redirect my homepage according to the detected country language. My PHP is auto-translating in multiple languages and I'm trying to avoid multiplying the same exact Site to subdomains and domains because of SEO - but looks like Google is not so advanced yet, giving no other choice.

e.g.

```
mysite.com  to:
mysite.com/index.php?lang=nl  for holland
mysite.com/index.php?lang=fr   for france
and for no specified country code just to:
mysite.com/index.php?lang=be

mysite.com/?lang=nl wwould also be fine
```

I'll also be happy to hear a better suggestion.
I tried the following with no succes

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^nl[NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.html /index\.php?lang=nl [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr[NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.html /index\.php?lang=fr [QSA,NC,L]
```

I'm just getting a server error - Couldn't find an exact case that could help

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(nl|fr) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)?$ /index.php?lang=%1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)?$ /index.php?lang=be [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: your code is opening the html index and not even redirecting to index php. No server error is returned but nothing else

Comment: Try now with the `be`  default language

Comment: The GET value sticks to (be) no matter what country. I think I might be able to use the php header Location or similar and just redirect before the page content is opened

Comment: I got it to work by using a combo from htaccess and PHP. Now my site is self-redirecting while auto-translating like: example.com/fr  example.com/se etc. Did not have to create new pages. Just need to work the other directories as well. However thank U 4 trying 2 help, you're nice.